# Bootstrap modal popup - change values when it closes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal popup which displays the date on the main screen along with a few drop down. The user can go to the next date and make the selection in the drop down and then press reserve. This will save selection of the date and the drop downs and give a notification that the information is saved.The popup does not close till the **x** or **close** button is clicked. My issue is that once its saved and the user clicks on **Close** , the dates selected in the popup should update the text-box in the main page and if the data was successfully changed, it should display that it was changes on the main page label once the popup closes.

[image]

Comment: So have you written any code to update the main page after the modal closes?

Comment: No Sir, I am using this for the first time.. I have made it so far but the on close event is not a bit out of my reach. I am using .net btw.

Comment: <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>  
but this is client side.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign an id to the close button. And write an on click function to change main page fields values with the modal values.